# Filter int number from Series Data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have Series with such data:

```
s = pd.Series(data=['1', 2, 3.1, 'hi!', 5, -512, 12.42, 'test', 10.10, 98], 
              index=range(2, 12, 1))
```

Which is the simplest way to filter integers from data in Series?
I need only integer number remain in data.

Thank you.

Comment: Would `10.0` qualify as an integer (as it's a float that can be perfectly represented as an integer) or are you strictly looking to do this based on the existing `type` of the values in your Series

Comment: Also, is `'1'` an integer as well?

Comment: By initial task definition '1' and 10.0 should not be treated as integers. Just type check. Sorry that I missed that mention first.
But it would be nice to see an option with also treating  '1' and 10.0 as integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a simple type check function and pass it with `pd.Series.apply`

```
s[s.apply(lambda x: type(x)==int)]
```

Note that Rob Raymond's answer performs better for large objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = pd.Series(data=['1', 2, 3.1, 'hi!', 5, -512, 12.42, 'sber', 10.10, 98.0], 
              index=range(2, 12, 1))

# strictly integers in input
s[pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce", downcast="signed").fillna(0).astype(int).eq(s)]

# allow strings and floats etc that are equivalent to integers
s[pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce", downcast="signed").fillna(0).astype(int).eq(pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=['1', 2, 3.1, 'hi!', 5, -512, 12.42, 'sber', 10.10, 98]

data = [float(v) for v in data if str(v).replace(".","").isdigit()]

print (data)

data=['1', 2, 3.1, 'hi!', 5, -512, 12.42, 'sber', 10.10, 98]

data = [int(v) for v in data if str(v).isdigit()]

print (data)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.1, 5.0, 12.42, 10.1, 98.0]
[1, 2, 5, 98]
```

Take your favorite